# How to convert string to string array in java

Tags: java

how to use Split() method , in such a way so that i can avoid the blank spaces.

Comment: Post the string you are trying to split, how are you splitting it (code), what you are getting and what you are expecting. The question as is, is quite vague.

Answer (score 9):

First trim() your String and then apply split() method.

I think your string has white spaces at end so first trim your string to remove the white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

First replace all the white spaces with blank String and then split it to String array.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     String test = "This is an example";
     String[] array = test.replaceAll(" ","").split("(?!^)");
     for (String letter : array)
     {
         System.out.print(letter+ " ");
     }
  }
```

The output is the following :

> T h i s i s a n e x a m p l e